# Install FreeNX on Maverick Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, freenx

I'm attempting to set up FreeNX on the standard Ubuntu Amazon EC2 AMI image.  (I'm using ami-af7e2eea).

Specifically, I'm trying to follow these directions: http://blog.restbackup.com/how-to-use-amazon-ec2-as-your-desktop?c=1 which worked fine on Lucid, but I needed to upgrade to a large instance (64-bit) and I needed to upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick.  I've been trying and failing to transmute these directions for Maverick.

Following the standard Ubuntu FreeNX documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX I was able to get freenx installed.  But when I log into it from Windows, the gnome-terminal I launch has a grey screen; I can't actually use it for anything.

I assume I'm not installing freenx correctly.  What should I be doing differently?  How do I troubleshoot a broken FreeNX installation?